# Xamarin.Forms AudioManager not toggling SpeakerPhone with Android 10, 11, 12, 13

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have this background service that toggles speakerphone during inbound/outbound calls without any success! Why and how can I fix it?

Thanks in Advance!!!!!!!

```
[Service]//(IsolatedProcess = true)]
public class PhoneCallService : Service
{
    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
    }

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        base.OnStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        MainActivity.audioManager = (AudioManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);
        int WaitTime = 30;

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (MainActivity.audioManager.SpeakerphoneOn)
                { MainActivity.audioManager.SpeakerphoneOn = false; }
                else { MainActivity.audioManager.SpeakerphoneOn = true; }
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(WaitTime));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This background service should toggle SpeakerPhone ON/OFF every thirty seconds during InBound/OutBound Calls. But it doesn't. It used to work on Android 10, 11, 12 but not now!
Perhaps on Android 13 there may be a different way to address this in Xamarin.Forms. Some of the methods I tried failed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue about this, you can follow it up here:

[SpeakerPhone not activating on Android 13 under Android Studio and Visual Studio](https://support.google.com/android/thread/186843566?hl=en).

And you can check the similar thread here:

[How to turn-on SpeakerPhone for incoming call in Xamarin.Forms Android 13](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1053246/how-to-turn-on-speakerphone-for-incoming-call-in-x).

Comment: Thank you those were posted by me.